# How long can the name of a type constructor be?

Tags: haskell

Is there a limit to how long a constructor name can be? What are the consequences of having absurdly long constructor names?

```
data F = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: *"What are the consequences of having absurdly long constructor names"*: For one, they don't fit in a StackOverflow comment.

Comment: This is the most pointless question I've ever upvoted :-)

Comment: One immediate consequence seems to be that the constructor name is present in the compiled file (even when the datatype isn't used for anything). My program declares the same type `F` as yours, and `main` is just `putStrLn "Hello."`, yet the strings utility shows the constructor name is present (once) in the file output by GHC 7.6.3.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all the consequences will be known.  For example, an old optimizer bug existed in which the inliner counted the function name length in the computation deciding whether to inline or not.

Comment: J. Abrahamson: asking the real hard line questions which never affect anyone at all! :)

Comment: I don't think there is a hard limit. Look at [this](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/intro.html#sect1.4) for constraints on namespaces in Haskell. There is no mention of length.

Comment: If you strip the binary, does it remove the constructor name from it? I would expect it's only present as a debugging aid.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If we check the [source for ghc](https://github.com/ghc/ghc), we can find the type used for defining data constructors. [It is named DataCon](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ghc-7.8.2-release/compiler/basicTypes/DataCon.lhs#L257), and it has the following field:

```
dcName    :: Name,  -- This is the name of the *source data con*
```

Going down the rabbit hole, [Name contains an OccName](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ghc-7.8.2-release/compiler/basicTypes/Name.lhs#L100):

```
n_occ  :: !OccName,     -- Its occurrence name
```

An [OccName](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ghc-7.8.2-release/compiler/basicTypes/OccName.lhs#L229) contains a `FastString` for the name:

```
data OccName = OccName
    { occNameSpace :: !NameSpace
    , occNameFS :: !FastString
    }
    deriving Typeable
```

Finally, a [FastString](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ghc-7.8.2-release/compiler/utils/FastString.lhs#L180) is just a `ByteString`, also with a precalculated length, and a int to tag it for quick comparison:

```
data FastString = FastString {
      uniq :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int, -- unique id
      n_chars :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int, -- number of chars
      fs_bs :: {-# UNPACK #-} !ByteString,
      fs_ref :: {-# UNPACK #-} !(IORef (Maybe FastZString))
  } deriving Typeable
```

There is no limit on the size of the string using this data type (except obviously `maxBound :: Int`). However that doesn't rule out a bug somewhere else in the code that may cause problems.

So we need a program to test this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Main where
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import System.IO (hPutStr, hFileSize, hClose)
import System.Exit (ExitCode(..))
import System.IO.Temp (withSystemTempFile)
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX (getPOSIXTime)
import System.Process (readProcessWithExitCode)

-- timing functions (from criterion)
getTime :: IO Double
getTime = (fromRational . toRational) `fmap` getPOSIXTime

time :: IO a -> IO (Double, a)
time act = do
  start <- getTime
  result <- act
  end <- getTime
  let !delta = end - start
  return (delta, result)



-- make a constructor like
-- data C = FFFFFF
makeConstructor :: Int -> String
makeConstructor size = "data C = " ++ replicate size 'F'

wrapWithMainModule :: String -> String
wrapWithMainModule code = unlines ["module Main where", "main = return ()", code]

data CompileResults = CompileResults {
  timeTaken :: Double,
  success :: Bool,
  outputFileSize :: Integer
  } deriving (Show)



compileHsCode :: String -> IO CompileResults
compileHsCode sourceCode = withSystemTempFile "test.hs" $ \path handle -> do
  withSystemTempFile "output.o" $ \outputPath outputHandle -> do
    hPutStr handle $ wrapWithMainModule sourceCode
    hClose handle
    (timeTaken, (exitCode, _, _)) <- time $ readProcessWithExitCode "ghc" ["-c", "-o", outputPath, path] ""
    let success = exitCode == ExitSuccess

    size <- if success then hFileSize outputHandle else return 0
    return $ CompileResults {
      timeTaken = timeTaken
      , success = success
      , outputFileSize = size
      }


testConstructorSizes :: [Int] -> IO ()
testConstructorSizes sizes = forM_ sizes $ \size -> do
  info <- compileHsCode $ makeConstructor size
  putStrLn $ "For Size " ++ show size ++ "\t: " ++ show info



-- Up to 10 million
sizesToTest :: [Int]
sizesToTest = take 7 (iterate (*10) 10)

main = testConstructorSizes $ sizesToTest
```

Here is the output of running `main`:

```
For Size 10     : CompileResults {timeTaken = 0.1390078067779541, success = True, outputFileSize = 1818}
For Size 100    : CompileResults {timeTaken = 0.14700841903686523, success = True, outputFileSize = 2086}
For Size 1000   : CompileResults {timeTaken = 0.1390080451965332, success = True, outputFileSize = 4786}
For Size 10000  : CompileResults {timeTaken = 0.1520085334777832, success = True, outputFileSize = 31786}
For Size 100000 : CompileResults {timeTaken = 0.31201791763305664, success = True, outputFileSize = 301786}
For Size 1000000        : CompileResults {timeTaken = 2.26712965965271, success = True, outputFileSize = 3001786}
For Size 10000000       : CompileResults {timeTaken = 109.2182469367981, success = True, outputFileSize = 30001786}
```

Few interesting points:

1. Note how the time taken increases massively after beyond 1 million. You would expect an increase of x10 if the change was linear, but it is a change of x50. This would likely mean for a 100 million character constructor, it would take about 5000 seconds to compile (which I didn't test).
2. The file size for the all of the entries was exactly `(1786 + (constructorSize * 3)`. So each char takes up three bytes when used in a constructor.

Comment: How about the file size if you use `module Main (main) where ...`?

Comment: @NicolasTrangez: That doesn't make a difference. Compiling to an executable (eg test-out.exe) rather than a library changes the initial size, but the executable size continues to increase with larger constructor names, even with -O3. Browsing the executable with vim, you can see the constructor name is included in the executable (I'm not sure why).